# How are connection complications on a single KLM+Kenya Airways itinerary handled?

Tags: air-travel, transit, short-connections, klm

Assume you book a trip from Stockholm-Amsterdam-Nairobi-Dzaoudzi (ARN-AMS-NBO-DZA) in a single booking through Kenya Airways (ARN-AMS being operated by KLM). The connection time in AMS and NBO is 1 hour and 4.5 hours respectively.

My questions are:

1. If the ARN-AMS flight is delayed, but not so much that the AMS-NBO flight has already left, does KLM have any procedure to get you to your next plane faster? In particular given that you clear immigration in AMS?
2. If you miss the connection either in AMS or NBO (the latter would be if the AMS-NBO flight is delayed by hours), would you normally get re-booked on a different itinerary getting you to DZA as quickly as possible, or only on the exact same route?

Comment: Did you end up booking that ticket?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, but I'm travelling in November

Comment: Call KLM customer service and particularly their Flying Blue lines if you have status. NBO to DZA only goes once every few days so there really is nothing like _getting you to DZA as quickly as possible_. You will be bogged down in NBO for at least another day, maybe two to catch the next flight to DZA. No other options.

Comment: @SheikPaul Telephone agents have very restricted authority to make changes compared to airport staff. I would suggest going to a ticket desk. If the person has status I would go to the ticket desk in the Crown Lounge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is a fast lane for short connections, but that is all. Do not expect KLM to arrange a car for you.
2. If you miss the connection at AMS, a computer program will attempt to rebook you automatically and you will be emailed your new reservations. The program is not very imaginative, by default they will put you on the same itinerary. You are not obliged to accept these reservations: you may wish to investigate alternatives yourself and present them to KLM; airport staff have wide authority to make alternative reservations in these circumstances. (This is different to call centre staff who do not have such authority: if you can, always talk to someone at the airport.) If you miss your connection at NBO, you will have to speak to someone at the transfers desk and again seek rerouting help.